# Open PDF in browser

Tags: android, android-intent

What I want to achieve is to display PDFs directly in browser.

```
private void openPDF(String url) {
         Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
         startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

With this method the PDF is downloaded, but I have to manually open it in order to see it.

I remember this method worked just fine a while a go, did something change in the intent or chrome maybe?

Comment: Few if any Android Web browsers have the built-in ability to view a PDF file. They will delegate that to some other app (Google Docs, Adobe Acrobat Reader, etc.). Whether any of those support `https` URLs is up to their developers. Similarly, the exact behavior of a Web browser with respect to downloading a PDF is up to the developer of the Web browser, and there are lots of Web browsers for Android. Please do not assume that everyone uses Chrome, or that Chrome will have the same UX over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
String format = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=%s";
String fullPath = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, format, "PDF_URL_HERE");
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fullPath));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

If this can help.

Comment: Tried this one but doesn't work if there's no google account linked to the device.